# Error in Pouplating all trailers "available" trailers stored in the database appear in a dropdownmenu of the order form so i can create the order

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-6

I just want to be able to populate all `available Trailers from the database in a dropdown menu` when creating an order. After which I should be able to change the trailer status to unavailable so `it does not appear in the dropdown menu anymore`. My program crashes when because I don't know how to accurately populate the trailers in the order form. I've tried everything i know.Below are some of my code.Trailer and Order is supposed to have a one on one relationship

```
public class Trailer
    {
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string TrailerNumber { get; set; }
        public string TrailerStatus { get; set; }

        public int TrailerID { get; set; }

        //has a one to one relationship with order
        public virtual Order orderforTrailer { get; set; }

        public Trailer()
        {
            TrailerStatus = "Avaliable";
        }
    }

 public class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    //has a one to one relationship with Trailer
    public virtual Trailer TrailerForLoad { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        OrderStatus = "Available";
    }
}

    public IActionResult Add()
    {
        // passes in the list of available trailers in the order form
        IList<Trailer> trailerForLoad = context.Trailers.Include     
        (c =>c.TrailerStatus == "Avaliable").ToList();

        AddOrderViewModel addOrderViewModel = new      
        AddOrderViewModel(trailerForLoad);

        return View(addOrderViewModel);
    }
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(AddOrderViewModel addOrderViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Order newOrder = new Order()
            {
                OrderNumber = addOrderViewModel.OrderNumber,       

                TrailerForLoad = context.Trailers.Where(x => x.TrailerID == addOrderViewModel.TrailerID).Single()

            };

            context.Orders.Add(newOrder);

            trailerSelected = context.Trailers.Where(x => x.TrailerID == addOrderViewModel.TrailerID).Single();

            trailerSelected.TrailerStatus = "Unavilable";
            context.SaveChanges();

            return Redirect("/Order");
        }

        return View(addOrderViewModel);
    }
 Trailer trailerSelected = new Trailer();
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained what the problem is. Creating a dropdown menu, and setting a control to disabled, are fairly easy things to do. Maybe hire a programmer?

Comment: well, the code I have above was my idea of trying to achieve this but I am apparently not achieving my aim as it crashes when I try to pull up the order form